# Creating a list of URLs from a specific website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my first attempt at using programming for something useful, so please bear with me. Constructive feedback is much appreciated :)

I am working on building a database with all press releases from the European Parliament. Until now, I have built a scraper that can retrieve the data I want from one specific URL. However, after reading and viewing a couple of tutorials, I still can't figure out how to create a list of URLs containing all the press releases from this specific site.

Maybe it's related to how the website is built, or I am (probably) just missing some obvious thing that an experienced programme would realise right away, but I don't really know how to proceed from here.

This is the start URL: http://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/press-room

This is my code:

```
links = [] # Until now I have just manually pasted a few links 
           # into this list, but I need it to contain all the URLs to scrape

# Function for removing html tags from text
TAG_RE = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')
def remove_tags(text):
    return TAG_RE.sub('', text)

# Regex to match dates with pattern DD-MM-YYYY
date_match = re.compile(r'\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d')

# For-loop to scrape variables from site
for link in links:

    # Opening up connection and grabbing page  
    uClient = uReq(link)

    # Saves content of page in new variable (still in HTML!!)
    page_html = uClient.read()

    # Close connection
    uClient.close()

    # Parsing page with soup
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    # Grabs page
    pr_container = page_soup.findAll("div",{"id":"website"})

    # Scrape date
    date_container = pr_container[0].time
    date = date_container.text
    date = date_match.search(date)
    date = date.group()

    # Scrape title
    title = page_soup.h1.text
    title_clean = title.replace("\n", " ")
    title_clean = title_clean.replace("\xa0", "")
    title_clean = ' '.join(title_clean.split())
    title = title_clean

    # Scrape institutions involved
    type_of_question_container = pr_container[0].findAll("div", {"class":"ep_subtitle"})
    text = type_of_question_container[0].text
    question_clean = text.replace("\n", " ")
    question_clean = text.replace("\xa0", " ")
    question_clean = re.sub("\d+", "", question_clean) # Redundant?
    question_clean = question_clean.replace("-", "")
    question_clean = question_clean.replace(":", "")
    question_clean = question_clean.replace("Press Releases"," ")
    question_clean = ' '.join(question_clean.split())
    institutions_mentioned = question_clean

    # Scrape text
    text_container = pr_container[0].findAll("div", {"class":"ep-a_text"})
    text_with_tags = str(text_container)
    text_clean = remove_tags(text_with_tags) 
    text_clean = text_clean.replace("\n", " ")
    text_clean = text_clean.replace(",", " ") # Removing commas to avoid trouble with .csv-format later on
    text_clean = text_clean.replace("\xa0", " ")
    text_clean = ' '.join(text_clean.split())

    # Calculate word count
    word_count = len(text_clean.split())
    word_count = str(word_count)

    print("Finished scraping: " + link)

    time.sleep(randint(1,5))

    f.write(date + "," + title + ","+ institutions_mentioned + "," + word_count + "," + text_clean + "\n")

    f.close()
```

Comment: html have current method for puting urls, in html we have : src, href and action for all links, for src=> ( 'script', 'img', 'source', 'video', 'audio', 'embed', 'iframe', 'input', 'track' ) , for href=> ( 'a', 'link', 'area', 'base' ) and for action=> ( 'form' ), first you need to extarct these tags, then extract their each src,href and action sub_tag ( without parsing anything or removing dirty strings ), with this method you can extract all standard html urls, you can do it with beautifulsoup module and two fors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the simple way to get list of required links with [`python-requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/) and [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/installation.html):

```
from lxml import html
import requests
url = "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/press-room/page/"
list_of_links = []
for page in range(10):
    r = requests.get(url + str(page))
    source = r.content
    page_source = html.fromstring(source)
    list_of_links.extend(page_source.xpath('//a[@title="Read more"]/@href'))
print(list_of_links)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I was wondering if you could clarify how I can know whether a website is dynamic or not? You method works for the first 15 links on the initial URL, but do I need the Selenium module to "click" on the load more button?

Comment: If content is in page source - it is static content, if it is generated by JavaScript - it is dynamic content. Simple put, you can check page source by right click on web page in browser: if you can find required content - it is static, if not - it is dynamic.

Comment: @DanielHansen, you can check updated answer which is applicable to first 10 pages (150 links). You can set bigger range or replace `for` loop with `while`

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the links using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` with only six liner code. Although the script is mostly identical to Sir Andersson, the library and the usage applied here is slightly different.

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/press-room/page/{}"
for url in [base_url.format(page) for page in range(10)]:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text,"lxml")
    for link in soup.select('[title="Read more"]'):
        print(link['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The first 15 URLs are obtainable without using the selenium module.

---

You can't use urllib.request (I assume this is what you are using) to obtain the URLs of the press releases, because the content of this site is dynamically loaded.

You may try to use the selenium module.

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/press-room')

# Click "Load More", repeat these as you like
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "continuesLoading_button")))
driver.find_element_by_id("continuesLoading_button").click()

# Get urls
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
urls = [a["href"] for a in soup.select(".ep_gridrow-content .ep_title a")]
```

Comment: No. This content is not dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You can read the official [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to get better at scraping. You should also check out [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/).

Here's a simple snippet for grabbing the required links from that page.
I am using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library in the following example. Let me know if you have any other queries.

*Although this script won't click on "Load more", and load additional releases.*
I'll leave that up to you ;) (Hint: Use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/))

```
def scrape_press(url):
    page = requests.get(url)

    if page.status_code == 200:
        urls = list()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
        body = soup.find_all("h3", {"class": ["ep-a_heading", "ep-layout_level2"]})
        for b in body:
            links = b.find_all("a", {"title": "Read more"})
            if len(links) == 1:
                link = links[0]["href"]
                urls.append(link)

        # Printing the scraped links
        for _ in urls:
            print(_)
```

**Note**: You should always read terms and conditions of a website before scraping any data.